# How do I get the users location latitude and longitude?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-location

I need to access the users location in this method contained in the mainViewController

```
-(void)loadAnnotations{
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
workingCoordinate.latitude= //here i need the users latitude
workingCoordinate.longitude= //here i need the users longitude
NSLog(@" this is %@", workingCoordinate.latitude);
iProspectLiteAnnotation *tempMine = [[iProspectLiteAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
[tempMine setTitle:@"Present Location"];
[tempMine setAnnotationType:iProspectLiteAnnotationTypeUser];
[mapView addAnnotation:tempMine];
}
```

however the mainViewController is already set to

```
<fipsideViewControllerDelegate>
```

What should I add to the header file and the implementation file to poll the location Manager for the users current latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your other question I already told you how to get the location, so:

[`-[CLLocation coordinate]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW7)

It never hurts to look in the documentation before posting questions...

Comment: So I just type that into the loadAnnotations method? I have looked at the documentation, but its like looking for a needle in a haystack. So many unnecessary things, and they all set the locationManager delegate to self, which I  cant do because the class is set to delegate the flipsideViewController

Comment: oh wow, i feel retarded now lol. simple misunderstanding of syntax.

Comment: however, now the program keeps crashing somewhere here:
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
 [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate = [location coordinate];
 NSLog(@" this is %@", workingCoordinate.latitude);