# Find latitude and longitude

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, latitude-longitude

Can any one help me in getting the latitude and longitude value of the place? The place details must be gotten from the user as a input. The place detail can be ZIP code, city name, address, or state code.

Comment: What place? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wanted to fine the lat and long of the cities inside United states

Comment: So you essentially want the lat/lng for an address?

Comment: So what have you tried? What has your research turned up? What did you find in the documentation? What have you done to attempt solving this problem yourself?

Comment: He user can give address or only cityname or only the state. for example he may give as 3198 GRATIOT BOULEVARD (or) MI (or) MARYSVILLE, MI

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the address of a latitude and longitude in an iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063717/how-to-get-the-address-of-a-latitude-and-longitude-in-an-iphone-application) or [Get the user's latitude and longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066036/)

Comment: Or possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387039/convert-the-address-into-latitude-and-longitude-for-google-maps-in-iphone

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+latitude+longitude+from+address&submit=search

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert an address into a lat/lng.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have used is to utilise the google maps API to return a lat/long for a given zip/postcode or city etc. Its normally quite good at dealing with different inputs.

Sadly I don’t have any C samples but could post up a VB.Net example if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to **geocode** the address. Since Mapkit doesn't support geocoding (only reverse-geocoding) you'll have to use a web service to accomplish that. The are [tons](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=geocoding) of web services for that. For example [Google Geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)